# On miscellaneous questions about perfect numbers I

Tags: elementary-number-theory, prime-numbers, totient-function, divisor-sum, prime-gaps

Let $\varphi(m)$ the Euler's totient function and $\sigma(m)$ the sum of divisors function.

If $n$ is an odd perfect number then $n$ satisfies $$\varphi(n)=\varphi(\sigma(n)).\tag{1}$$

The sequence of integers satisfying $(1)$ is defined in The On-Line Encyclopedia of Integer Sequences as sequence [*A006872*](https://oeis.org/search?q=A006872&sort=&language=&go=Search) (see also the references).

> **Question.** I would like to know if in the context of our condition $(1)$ we can set a lower bound and an upper bound 
>    $$\text{Lower bound}<\pi(2n)-\pi(n)<\text{Upper bound}\tag{2}$$
>   where $\pi(x)$ denotes the prime-counting function, and $n$ being an odd perfect number. **Many thanks.**

I hope that the identity $(1)$ is a good motivation for asking my Question.